# HashMap with an int value as a key

Tags: java, hashmap, int

I am trying to create a HashMap with one key a string and the other an int. However, my IDE doesn't like it when I try to put an int as a key when creating a HashMap. Here is what I have currently:

```
private HashMap<String, int> exp = new HashMap<String, int>();
```

However, my IDE gives errors where I have "int", saying "Syntax error, insert "Dimensions" to complete ReferenceType". But I don't know what that means. So how would I use an int as a key in a HashMap?

Comment: Note that the int/Integer is the map *value*, not its key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int` is a primitive type. Use `Integer` instead.

```
private HashMap<String, Integer> exp = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```